# Get select options for a field in a sublist within a Netsuite client script

Tags: netsuite

How does one get the select options for a dropdown in a sublist, using a client script?  I'm looking to get the values of the dropdown in the screenshot.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up the values in the DB, and set the field to the record ID I wanted.  It's not ideal, but it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nlapiGetField('website')` (or whatever the ID of that column field is) to retrieve the `nlobjField` for the dropdown, then call the `getSelectOptions()` method on the field object, like so:

```
var fieldOptions = nlapiGetField('website').getSelectOptions();
```

Comment: I tried that first, sadly getSelectOptions is only available server-side https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3140379.html#bridgehead_N3141217. That is essentially what I wanted to do though :).